# Use values from values.yaml inside named template in Helm v2/v3

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I cannot get a value from values.yaml inside named template section, but it is available outside of the section.

I would really appreciate if somebody can clarify what is wrong.

Helm 2 and Helm 3 have the same behaviour.

**Simple example**
templates/test.yaml

```
{{- define "test" -}}
# Inside define section: {{ .Values.env }}
{{- end -}}
{{ template "test"}}
---
# Outside define section: {{ .Values.env}}
```

values.yaml

```
env: env-placeholder
```

Output

```
> helm template .
---
# Source: helm-configs-template/templates/test.yaml
# Inside define section:
---
# Source: helm-configs-template/templates/test.yaml
# Outside define section: env-placeholder
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my question. I forgot to add a dot to

```
{{ template "test" .}}
```